# Java filter failing to set response headers

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, request, servlet-filters

I am trying to create a Java "Filter" which detects a custom HTTP Request Header, and inserts response headers so that the file will download automatically.  The response header that is most important for this is the "Content-Type = Attachment" response header.  I have created an HTTP request object that inserts the custom Header:

```
function myHttpObject(filePath){
function makeHttpObject() {
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}

var request = makeHttpObject();

request.open("GET", filePath, false);
request.setRequestHeader("X-Wria-Download", "PDFdownload");
request.send(null);
window.open(filePath);
console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
}
```

This will insert the X-Wria-Download header into the request.
Then I have a Java Filter which looks for that request header and should set the response header to "Content-Type=attachment"

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Contenttypefilter implements Filter  {

protected FilterConfig filterConfig;

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

public void destroy() {
    //noop
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    //get the headers we placed in the request
    //based on those request headers, set some response headers

    if(req.getHeader("X-Wria-Download") != null){
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=success.pdf");
    }

    chain.doFilter(req,res);
}


}
```

And then of course the web.xml has the code to include the Filter on all jsp files.

The thing that is baffling me, is that the header is being set on the response file, but it is not downloading as it should.  If I put the res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=success.pdf"); line outside the "if" statement, then it will work, but it will apply the download behavior to all JSP's which I don't want.

Why is it applying the content-disposition but not working when I have the res.setHeader in the if statement; and then working when it is outside the if statement?  Any ideas for how I can get the desired behavior (only applying content disposition to jsp's that I have applied a custom request header to)?

Comment: Are you sure that X-Wria-Download is correctly received in Java? Can you try to print req.getHeader("X-Wria-Download") and see if it is actually received correctly in the Java filter?

Comment: Yes it is receiving it correctly.  In the above "if" statement: if(req.getHeader("X-Wria-Download") != null){} it enters the statement and if i put in a System.out.println it will print that line out.  I also applies the Content-Disposition to the file, but the Content-Type seems to get overwritten at the chain.Filter stage.  Even though the response gets the Content-Disposition, it doesn't seem to behave as if it did (doesn't download, but rather pulls up the pdf as a page.)  I also see the "X-Wria-Download" in the request header when using Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Strangely if the:
     res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
     res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=success.pdf");

is put outside of the if statement, then the filter will work.  This doesn't solve my problem though since I only want the filter applied to servlets which I have attached my custom header to.

Comment: Added an answer with my comments about that.

Answer (score 12):

I think your issue is related to the Filter order of execution of your `Web Context`, i.e. some filters, in you web context, executes after your filter and override the header.

The Servlet [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is an implementation of the [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern

So you may try to:

- Set the headers after the call to chain.doFilter:

.

```
...

chain.doFilter(req,res);

HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

//get the headers we placed in the request
//based on those request headers, set some response headers

if(req.getHeader("X-Wria-Download") != null){
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=success.pdf");
}
```

In this way your code will be executed after that the Servlet is called and, as explained below, if your filter is the first declared in web.xml, then the `setHeader` code will be the last executed (see image below).

- make sure that your filter is the last to be executed after the Servlet is executed, i.e. it should be the first servlet Filter declared as explained [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm):

[image]

As you can see Filter1 (the first declared in web.xml) is the first one executed before the servlet is executed and the last one executed after the servlet is executed. So if you want to be sure to be the last Filter setting the header then declare it as Filter1.

The order of execution is determined by the order of declaration in your Deployment Descriptor (web.xml):

> Servlet spec (section 6.2.4):
>
> "The order the container uses in building the chain of filters to be
>   applied for a particular request URI is as follows:
>
> "1. First, the  matching filter mappings in the same
>   order that these elements appear in the deployment descriptor.
>
> "2. Next, the  matching filter mappings in the same
>   order that these elements appear in the deployment descriptor."

So to be sure simply declare it as the first filter in your `web.xml`. In this way it will be the very last filter setting the header. And, of course, set the header in your code after calling `chain.doFilter`, as already said.

Comment: thanks! the key things that helped me from this is that 1) Make sure your filter is added first, so it will get called last, and 2) make sure you modify the response *after* calling chain.doFilter(req,res), not before, or your response may get overwritten.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me using Dropwizard 0.6 / Jetty 8. (I'm trying to modify cookie values.) For some reason, no matter where I add the `chain.doFilter()` call, my response comes back with the original values of the headers. I've had to solve my problem in a different, less desirable way, but I'm just commenting on this answer in case anyone else has had issues too.

Comment: Thanks for the good description. I've tried to do such a filter with Jetty 9.2 but unfortunately it also didn't work, seems to be the same issue as @DuffJ had. In my case the filter worked as expected only if I declared it as last filter in my `web.xml`.

Comment: Note that if you add headers after `chain.doFilter()`, but farther down the filter chain the headers were already committed (such as, because enough data was already written), your headers will never get sent.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you use a response wrapper as described here by others, the whole secret is when to call getWriter() on the original response! That's because the response object ignores all headers added AFTER you asked for a writer!

So, make sure you add all your headers Before you call getWriter().
Here is my recommended sequence for doFilter():

1. Create a response wrapper
2. chain.doFilter (origRequest, wrapper);
3. Assign all required headers to the original (!) Response
4. Get writer from original response
5. Copy the wrapper's content to this writer

Answer (score 0):

Try this: set an attribute on the request if the request header is present.  Then, check for the attribute after the `chain.doFilter(...)` and set the response headers then.

Comment: Ok so I've tried doing this.  For some reason, after the chain.doFilter, the content-type always reverts back to text/html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the header(X-Wria-Download) of your AjaxRequest (here XMLHttpRequest) is not being set in your HttpServletRequest object before the filter is being served.

I think better Idea will be to  **use a Dedicated Servlet to handle your ajax request**.

Comment: The header(X-Wria-Download) actually does seem to be getting applied to the request object before being passed to the java Filter.  When going through the Filter in debug mode it detects the custom request header, and subsequently executes the if statement above:  if(req.getHeader("X-Wria-Download") != null){}.