# CORS issue with rest service hosted in Adobe CQ

Tags: jquery, filter, cors, aem, sling

We have CORS issue with rest service hosted in Adobe CQ (Please note that this is a proof of concept application only). To fix this, we have added a simple filter to set required response headers.
The code for the filter is some thing like

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request instanceof SlingHttpServletRequest
            && response instanceof SlingHttpServletResponse) {
        SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) request;
        SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = (SlingHttpServletResponse) response;

        slingResponse.addHeader("Access-control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        slingResponse.addHeader("Access-control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        slingResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

        filterChain.doFilter(slingRequest, slingResponse);

    }
```

We are using a Jquery script to fire a GET request to the CQ Service to get some JSON value produced by Jercy (MOXY).

```
    $(function(){                
        $("#getPerson").on("click", function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://san.dev.local.com:4502/services/person/get",
                type: "GET",                    crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                    if($.trim(data) == "false") {
                        alert("Fail to recive");
                      }
                      else {
                        alert("Successfully data recived");

                      }
                } ,error : function(err){

                    console.log(err);
                    alert("Error : "+err);
                    //YOUR CODE FOR AJAX FAILURE  

                  }
            });
        });                
    });
```

[But the accept header of the ajax request shows "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8]"  is this ok?]

Note: Our service/Resource is annotated with

```
@Path("/get")
@GET     
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public Person getPerson() {
 .......................
 .......................
   }
```

But whenever we send an AJAX request, to get person data we are getting a CORS error

```
    04:46:47.497 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the 
remote resource at http://san.dev.local.com:4502/services/person/get?_=1442467869174. 
  (Reason: CORS request failed).1 <unknown>
```

Note:

We have used an intercepting proxy to examine the request and response (OWASP ZAP).

Request

```
  OPTIONS http://san.dev.local.com:4502/services/person          /get?_=1442467869171   HTTP/1.1
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:40.0)     Gecko/20100101          Firefox/40.0
   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
   Origin: http://san.dev.local.com:8080
   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
   Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
   Connection: keep-alive
   Host: san.dev.local.com:4502
```

Response

```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Server: Day-Servlet-Engine/4.1.52
   Content-Type: text/html
   Content-Length: 0
   Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 05:32:24 GMT
   Allow: GET,OPTIONS,HEAD
```

Surprisingly, the response header

```
    Access-control-Allow-Origin
```

is missing in the response.

Any pointers to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.

### Update

For me it seems that some or the other filter is overriding our settings. If so, is there a way to handle this scenario.

Just now we found this post : [Java filter failing to set response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461500/java-filter-failing-to-set-response-headers).

Modified the filder properties by adding a service ranking property to keep the filter up in the possibel stack.

```
 @Properties({ @Property(name = "filter.scope", label = "scope", value = "REQUEST"),
    @Property(name = "filter.order", label = "order", value = "2"),
    @Property(name = "service.ranking", intValue = 1)})
```

But this also not helped us. Any pointers will be helpful for us.

Thanks in advance,
San

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the reason you are getting the CORS error is because there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* value in your response header.  In you filter servlet have you tried specifying a specific domain (ex. http://san.dev.local.com:8080)?

You could also try creating a regular servlet and see if the headers are returned.

The filtering should be chained. Maybe add a custom response header value (myvar: success) to make sure it's being returned from your filter.  You could always hook up a debugger to see what the call stack looks like and potentially figure out what other filters are being used.