# Adding Response Header using AspectJ spring

Tags: java, spring, header, annotations, aop

I'm trying to add a response header to all the responses in my java application, to do that I'm using AspectJ.

In other words, what I want to do is, in the moment before the Response is being returned (and before building it) I want to add a header response so by adding the @PointCut and @AfterReturning I try to catch the response in order to add the header

The problem is I tried to debug but it dosen't reach the aspect, maybe the @PointCut executtion syntax isn't good ??

and is using @AfterReturning helps me ?

Thanks for the help, Jay

here's my code :

Responses to the client are returned in that way:

```
public Response getCustomer(...) {
...
return Response.ok(costumers).build();
}
```

Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {


    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut="execution(public Response *.*(..)",
            returning="response")
    public void updateStatisticsResponseHeader(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object response) {

        long longEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        Response resp1 = (Response) response;
        Object startTime  = resp1.getMetadata().get("start-time");
        long longStartTime = (long)startTime;
        long totalTime = longEndTime - longStartTime;

        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.fromResponse(resp1);
        responseBuilder.header("total-time",String.valueOf(totalTime));

        responseBuilder.build();

    }

}
```

beans.xml:

```
<bean id="MyAspect" class="com.project.aspect.MyAspect"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use aop for that? Consider using servlet filter. Of course, if you are using servlets.

Comment: Hi, I'm using servlets yes, but I need to add the header to the response just before it is being returned to the user.
I'm trying to return the total-time spent until the user received a response.

Comment: so you can add that header in the filter added last in your filter chain. And in that filter set your header after invoking chain.doFilter(..). Example is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461500/java-filter-failing-to-set-response-headers

Comment: @pomkine I need to set the header just before the response being returned, because I need the total time spent on request, and also because methods like getCustomer(...) and more have some logics that may take a while until proceed.
and putting it after the chain.doFilter() will not set the header since it has been returned to the client.